# selecting elements from a column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel, I have three columns A2:A100, B2:B50, C2:C50. I want to do the following things:

If An (n is any number between 2 and 100) is in B2:B50 AND Bm==An for some m, then let Dn=Cm.

How can I do it?

---

[Added] Here I suppose A2:A100 is a column of different students' names and B2:B50 is a column of a subset of the students' names and C2:C50 is the column of the test scores of the students in B2:B50.

Bm==An for some m means the student's name appears in both A and B at the same time. I want to put the corresponding scores in Cm to Dn.

For example, if student B2 appears in A50, then put the value C2 to D50. If student B5 appears in A66, then put the value C5 to D66.

Comment: What do you mean by "If An is in B2:B50"? Like if Cell B3 had value "A25" in it, or if B3 happened to contain a value that was in A2:A100? Furthermore, what do you mean by "Bm=An" What is Bm in this scenario? The cell that contained "A25"? Lastly, what do you mean by "Let Dn=Cm" What should we let them be? Perhaps an example would help out.

Comment: @JNevill, Thank you for your comment. Edited accordingly.

Comment: So... If a student in B2 (for instance) should appears in A2:A100 at some point, then take the score that is in C2 and put it in D2?

Comment: @JNevill Say, if student B2 appears in A50, then put the value C2 to D50. If student B5 appears in A66, then put the value C5 to D66.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments above:

In D2: `=if(iserror(vlookup(A2, $B$2:$C$50, 2, false)), "", vlookup(A2, $B$2:$C$50, 2, false))`

Copy that formula down to D100 and you should be good to go.

What it's doing:

The most important part is the `vlookup`. This takes a value (A2) and looks it up in the first column of a multiple-column range (B2:C50). If it find the value in the range than it returns the corresponding value in the second (2) column in that multi-column range. The "False" is used like 99% of the time so ignore it for now.

The `vlookup` function is then wrapped in an if statement to see if it errors. In the event that the value (A2) isn't found in the range (B2:C50) it will return a `#N/A`, so the `=IF(ISERROR(` part just tests to see if it's an error or not. If it is, then it returns nothing ("") else it it returns the results of the vlookup.

Instead of `=IF(ISERROR(vlookup), "", vlookup)` you could also do `=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$50, A2)>0, "", Vlookup)` where the countif function would check to make sure there is at least on instance of the student's name in B2:B50 before allowing the vlookup to do it's magic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you elaborate a little bit so that I can apply to a more general setting?

Comment: I've added to the answer with an explanation on what it's doing. The short of it is: Vlookup is a powerful formula that you'll find yourself using ALL the time in excel once you get used to it.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. Thank you very much!